# How can validate psr-jwt token on api call?

Tags: php, backend, slim

I am using https://github.com/RobDWaller/psr-jwt library in my slim4 application

I want to validate the token on the API call.

How should I do to recive the token and decode it?

Here my code:

```
public function view_token(Request $request, Response $response, array $args): Response {

    $token = get_token(); //What I do here?

    $response->getBody()->write($token);
    return $response;
}


$app->group('/test', function (Group $group){
    $group->get('/view_token', Tests::class . ':view_token');
})->add(JwtMiddleware::html(AUTH_SECRET, 'jwt', 'Authorisation Failed'));
```

The call arrives but I don't know how to get the token to extract the information

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://github.com/RobDWaller/psr-jwt#parse-and-validate-json-web-token